# AngularJS - Toaster not working in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-http

**Service.js**

```
this.userLogin = function (username, password) {

        var dataBody = $.param({'username': username,'password': password});
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: servicePathURL,
            data: dataBody,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic",
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }
        })

        .then(function (response) {
            $rootScope.globals = {
                currentUser: {
                    username: username,
                }
            };
            return response;

        }).catch(function (error) {
            throw error;
        });
    };
```

**Controller.js**

```
AuthenticationServiceLogin.userLogin($scope.username, $scope.password)

            .then(function (response) {

                if (response.status ==200) {   
                    toaster.pop('success', "", "Login Successful");
                    $location.path('/home');
                }

            }).catch(function (error) {
                toaster.pop('error', "", error.statusText);
        });
```

1. In Controller.js, `toaster.pop('error', "", error.statusText);` is not being called when there is an exception while user logs in.
2. Also I have used `$http` method, is there any advantage to returning
   a `$q.defer()` promise rather than an `$http` promise or considered as best practice ? If yes, how can I modify above `$http` code into `promise` ?

Comment: Where is the exception you're encountering being thrown from? Assuming you don't have any other catch calls hidden somewhere consuming the error, the error should be propagated just fine.

Comment: The toaster is not called in controllers catch function.

Comment: Have you tried removing the catch expression that you've got in service.js?

Comment: If I remove catch from service.js, I do not see catch block being called in controller.

Comment: Is .catch(...) being called in service.js at all then? It doesn't seem like it would be?

Comment: Any chance you could update your question with details of the HTTP response that catch isn't being thrown for? Statuscode, response body etc?

Comment: If I input invalid credentials, an remove catch block from service.js, it does not propagate to controllers catch block. If I keep it, i can see `invalid credentials` exception in console.log but then again toaster do not appear for the same.

Comment: Could you add information about the invalid credentials exception you're getting to the question? Screenshot, HTTP status, message, anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to be fine. So long as you re-throw any errors encountered by your `$http` call, they *should* propagate all the way up to the controller. I'm inclined to say that any problems with your error handling are not in the code that you've posted.

There's no advantage to having a catch handler in service.js if you're not going to do any work with the error thrown. Service.js will want to look like this:

**Service.js**

```
this.userLogin = function (username, password) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: servicePathURL,
        data: $.param({'username': username,'password': password}),
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        $rootScope.globals = {
            currentUser: {
                username: username,
            }
        };
        return response;
    // The catch block here is useless. The promise returned by $http will transmit any
    // errors on its own.        
    //}).catch(function (error) { 
    //    throw error;
    });
};
```

In response to your second question: there is no advantage to using `$q.defer()` instead of returning the promise returned by `$http` itself, and a number of major disadvantages - namely that any exceptions thrown by your login method will disappear. See The Deferred Anti-pattern here for details: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns

`$http` is definitely the preferred option.

Comment: Could you post relevant code considering above snippet ? And you suggest that sticking to `$http` is preferred option over `%q` ? If I remove catch block from service.js, the error do not propagate to controllers catch block.

Comment: I updated my code as above and removed catch from service.js. Although the error propagates to catch block of controller but it still toaster do not work there `toaster.pop('error', "", error.statusText);` Also what use I can make of error thrown in service catch block ?

Comment: Sorry, are you saying that `toaster.pop(...)` isn't working, or that execution isn't even getting there at all? My point about the catch block is that it's entirely unnecessary to have one in Service.js - you should only include a catch handler if you're actually going to do something with the error, like log it, or display it to the user. It'd be really helpful if you included details of the HTTP response being sent from the server. Is it 401/200/404?

Comment: Yes the execution is getting to controllers catch block and I can log the error from server as well. HTTP response is 401 when invalid credentials while correct credentials redirects user to home page with successful login toaster message. But for server error, toaster is not being generated when it goes to controllers catch block

Comment: toaster is just a service being injected into the controller right? Any extra information about the code around your authentication call in controller.js would be helpful.